# How can I confirm which RDBMS I'm using (in any form of SQL)?

Tags: sql, rdbms

I'm writing instructions for people who are completely new to SQL and who are probably using an interface to talk to the database. The interface might be a SQL editor provided by their workplace, or it might be software (e.g. a BI reporting system) that allows them to write a query rather than use the gui. These are business people, not IT.

The first thing I want them to do is identify which RDBMS they have, so we can establish which type of SQL they need to learn. I.e. is it Oracle, Microsoft, MySQL, PostGre et al. I feel silly asking this: but is there an SQL command that works across all RDBMS to tell them this? The closest I've got is select version(), but this only gives the version number, not the RDBMS name. And anyway it isn't consistently implemented.

Answer (score 2):

If the ANSI information schema is available:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.sql_implementation_info;
```

In particular the "DBMS NAME" and "DBMS VERSION" fields.

Comment: Does not work for SQL Server 2012 or lower, at least. ["Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 and Microsoft SQL Server 2012 vary as follows: Transact-SQL does not support this feature."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh544618(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Maybe the ANSI information schema is optional there and needs to be installed/enabled seperately. It is supposed to be cross-implementation.

Comment: Micrsoft SQL Server supports many `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views, but not `SQL_IMPLEMENTATION_INFO`. Yes, it's part of the ANSI standard. No, Microsoft SQL Server doesn't implement it.

Comment: Not implemented in SQL Server 2014 either.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote, but @emma should definitely know that this answer will not work if there is any possibility her users are connecting to Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: I dont care about downvotes, but it is obvious that MS has left out the most trivial part of information_schema when implementing it. Also: the most crucial, since this is basically the catalog bootstrap for every client.

Comment: The sql_implementation_info table doesn't exist in my MySQL information_schema

Answer (score 0):

Usually, if they are using some sort of BI system, you can simply check the configuration of the software where the connection parameters are set